# How to securley pass Password as Argument to a Python Script over SSH?

Tags: python, security, ssh

I have a python script that creates a linux user, given a username and password as arguments. I want to

- call the script directly (e.g, `./pass.py`)
- call the script on the same VM from
  python (e.g, `subprocess.Popen('/pass.py')`)
- call the script from a different VM from python over
  SSH. (e.g, `subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'host', 'pass.py')`)

**TL;DR Check the final code snippit and question**

`getpass` works for the first case.

```
password = getpass.getpass()
```

However, if I run this over ssh, (`ssh myhost /path/to/script.py username`) I get the following output:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/getpass.py:83: GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
  passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Password: password123
```

Also, if I run this script in python using `subprocess`:

```
# Running from same host
proc = subprocess.Popen(['./pass.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
# Running from different host
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'myhost', '/path/to/pass.py', 'username'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It seems to hang around `subprocess.Popen` and won't accept the password.

However, if I get rid of `getpass.getpass()` and replace it with `raw_input`, it works for cases 2 and 3. It doesn't echo the password.

I am therefore thinking of the following instead, which takes `--script` as an argument and asks for the password via `raw_input`:

```
import sys, getpass, argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("username")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--script", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
username = args.username
if args.script:
    password = raw_input("Password: ")
else:
    password = getpass.getpass()
```

This satisfies all three of my cases and does not appear to be echoing the password.

Am I correct in assuming that this is safe and the password won't get logged?

Answer (score 1):

You can add -t during SSH session, that will enforce an echo free terminal. On your client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

subprocess.call(["ssh", "-t", remote_host, "./add_user.py", "test_user"])
```

Then you should be able to use getpass on your server for a remote password. You can also call it directly or invoking through another script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import getpass, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("username")
args = parser.parse_args()
username = args.username
password = getpass.getpass()
```