# How to prevent Python's subprocess from printing the standard out when calling the Linux passwd utility?

Tags: python

When I use `subprocess` I can normally capture the stdout and display it however I like. E.g,

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['./foo.py'], stdin=subprocess.Pipe, stdout=subprocess.Pipe)
# the standard out is not displayed unless I do something with the stdout var
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

However, if I use `subprocess` to call the Linux `passwd` utility, the standard out is displayed as soon as proc.communicate() is called:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['passwd', 'foo'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# standard out is displayed immediately
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate('password\npassword\n')
BAD PASSWORD: it is based on a dictionary word
Retype new password:
```

How come this happens only with `passwd`? For example, it doesn't happen with `ls`. Is there anything I can do to prevent the standard out from being printed when calling `passwd` from `subprocess`?

Note that I want to actually capture the standard out and do something with it later, so I would not want to set stdout to a devnull pipe.

Comment: Do you capture both stdout and stdin? I'm bad with Python but i know you should capture both.

You could also alter /etc/shadow and /etc/passwd directly.

Comment: Aside: It doesn't actually matter for the immediate use case, but as a matter of practice, you should probably be explicit about handling of stderr.

Comment: @Gala, altering `/etc/shadow` directly is dangerous -- it means that an update to a system's PAM configuration (say, disabling a hash algorithm) could suddenly cause this program to effectively disable accounts by storing their passwords in an unsupported format; alternately, with a remote store (NIS, LDAP, etc), it could simply have no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

It only happens with `passwd` because `passwd` directly communicates with the TTY, not via stdin or stdout. This is a security measure, and accepted best practice for prompting for a password directly from a user.

If you **really** must bypass this security measure, consider using the `unbuffer` utility (shipped with `expect`) to create a fake TTY:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['unbuffer', 'passwd', 'foo'],
  stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate('password\npassword\n')
```

Comment: The script that I'm writing is going to be called by another script over SSH, where the password is inputted by `getpass.getpass()`. Does this still prevent a security concern? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631546/how-to-securley-pass-password-as-argument-to-a-python-script-over-ssh

Comment: Reading the password into your program's memory without using `mlock()` to prevent that memory from being swapped out (and possibly taking anti-`ptrace` precautions as well) isn't particularly good form. Whether this level of paranoia makes sense for you and your site is a judgment call for you to make.

Comment: Thanks. Ok I installed `unbuffer` via yum, however this command is hanging on `(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate('password\npassword\n')`. Any idea if I need to configure `unbuffer/expect` before using it? If I just execute `unbuffer passwd foo` on the terminal, it prompts me for a password but hangs after I enter it.

Comment: No configuration needed, no. Chances are that `passwd` is rejecting the password for some reason, and reprompting (such that it's still waiting for input). Since you're redirecting its prompts, you don't know what that the content it's waiting for *is*. :)

Comment: If you want something more powerful (with the ability to time out, for instance, or recognize prompts and error messages), consider using `pexpect`.

Comment: ...alternately, for your immediate debugging, you could redirect only stdin through the pipeline, and let stdout and stderr go through to your console.

Comment: If I run `passwd foo` and give the same password, it gets accepted. Actually what I only want to do is print out the `passwd` standard outs such that they are tabbed in so that its a bit more pretty.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: In Python's case, `mlock` is not an option; if you're reading and storing user passwords without the aid of a specialized extension module (and `getpass` doesn't count; it returns a `str` which can't be given special protections), the password is eligible for being swapped out. The usual rule is that if the system requires this level of security, it should be configured to encrypt the page file during operation, and clear it on shutdown.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen, have you followed the suggestion I gave and temporarily stopped redirecting stdout and stderr, so you can see them immediately?

Comment: @ShadowRanger, ...does Linux still not zero on free automatically? I'm a bit dismayed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Well, when you're worried about `ptrace`, the odds of the memory having been actually `free`-ed are not great in Python. Python uses their own internal arena based allocator; unless all objects in an arena are released, the arena is not returned to the OS until program exit. Linux doesn't necessarily zero pages even when returned to the OS, but it does guarantee they'll be zeroed before being handed out to any user space program; it's not 1980s level security here. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger, ...to be clear, btw, I didn't mean to imply above that proper paranoia was possible in Python. Rather the contrary.